# Setup an Ubuntu server (with nginx) to catch all domains with a certain DNS and display the same php file

Tags: 16.04, server, php, dns, nginx

I have dozens of undeveloped domains and I want them to display the same .php file for all of them by just pointing them to the same DNS:

ns1.example.com
ns2.example.com

Both NS are pointing to my VPS IP address but pages are not working.

I want that any domain I configure with that DNS point to the VPS and display the same php file automatically.

I have Ubuntu Server 16.04 + nginx + php-fpm working fine.

How can I achieve this by just configuring nginx? Is it necessary to configure Bind? How?

Thanks in advance,

Mos.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a default server without specifying server name, it will respond to every domain that's not explicitly set in other server blocks.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    server_name _;

    #your php config
}
```